# ajax call catch event not working on Bootstrap switch inside datatables plugin on responsive view

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, bootstrap-switch

Ajax call catch event not working on Bootstrap switch inside datatables plugin on responsive view.

```
$('.switch').bootstrapSwitch();
$('.switch').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function () 
{
    var id =$(this).attr("attrid");  
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'<?php echo base_url();?>parties/party_status_ajax',
        data:{'id':id,'checked':$(this).bootstrapSwitch('state')},
        success: function (data)
        {
            $('.close').click();
            $('#successmessage').html(data); 
        }
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you are binding the event to an element that doesn't exist in the html when that code runs, you need to use [delegated events](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) in order to bind it to subsequent elements of the datatable

something like below

```
$( "#dataTable tbody" ).on( "switchChange.bootstrapSwitch", ".switch", function() {
   var id =$(this).attr("attrid");  
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'<?php echo base_url();?>parties/party_status_ajax',
        data:{'id':id,'checked':$(this).bootstrapSwitch('state')},
        success: function (data)
        {
            $('.close').click();
            $('#successmessage').html(data); 
        }
    });
});
```